# GetJSON data from an API is NOT working when passing api url as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson, json-api

This function below is working 100% fine,

```
     function myFunction() {
        $(function () {
            $.getJSON('abc/url', function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
    }
```

But, when I try this (below) then it is not working even it does not show any errors. Can anyone tell why is it so? or the API url will always be hard coded?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
     function myFunction() {
         var URL = document.getElementById('textboxID').value;
        $(function () {
            $.getJSON(URL , function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
    }
 </script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
    link:
    <input id="textboxID" type="text">
    <input onclick="myFunction()" type="submit">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try logging the value of URL in the second case. What do you get after `console.log(URL)` ?

Comment: @Coder , can you provide the HTML you are working with?

Comment: What kind of error are you expect to get?

Comment: Why do you call $.getJSON inside $(function(){ ... that's a jQuery way of waiting for the DOM to be ready, but without the DOM being ready you cant get the textboxID's value either. Try just removing the call to $(function(){...

Comment: @john is right. Remove this line $(function () {

Comment: @JohnCaprez That is not the reason it doesn't work, though could be removed.

Comment: @NightRyder That is not the reason it doesn't work, though could be removed.

Comment: @LGSon if you put the variable URL inside the $(function (){.... Will it work or not?

Comment: @NightRyder If you check one of the answers, you can see it work as is, so the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: @Coder If you wan't a proper answer, provide a _working_ code snippet within the question, reproducing the issue you describe.

Comment: Done!, check it

Comment: It works when you remove <form> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works by removing form tag,

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
 function myFunction() {
     var URL = document.getElementById('textboxID').value;
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON(URL , function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
}
 </script>
</head>

<body>
link:
<input id="textboxID" type="text">
<input onclick="myFunction()" type="submit">

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code works for me , look a example api url in my code

```js
   function myFunction1() {
        $(function () {
            $.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users/hadley/orgs', function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
    }


     function myFunction2() {
         var URL = document.getElementById('textboxID').value;
        $(function () {
            $.getJSON(URL , function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='textboxID' value='https://api.github.com/users/hadley/orgs'>
<button onclick='myFunction1()'>function1</button>
<button onclick='myFunction2()'>function2</button>
```